# New Tag For Android Quick Settings Tiles

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-process

I've had a couple of questions about making my own quick settings tile for my Android app and I noticed that other than [android-n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-n) and [service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service) there isn't a tag that specifically refers to the quick settings tiles.

I would try to create the tag myself, but I am under 1500 rep on stack overflow. Is there a way I can submit a request to add a tag for these tiles or if possible could someone else try to create a tag for these tiles?

Comment: NB, [android-n] should be a synonym of [android-7.0-nougat].